# VBA to Sort by account number then select active cells, cut and paste to next sheet

Tags: vba, excel

So i recorded a macro to make the header row filters, then sort in column B "accounts" select a particular account number, then cut all those cells (minus the header row of course) and paste it onto sheet 2.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$1923").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        "905263043"
    Rows("180:180").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 184
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 202
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 217
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 234
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 249
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 266
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 284
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 301
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 316
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 333
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 345
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 363
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 380
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 400
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 425
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 447
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 477
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 531
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 559
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 606
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 663
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 725
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 757
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 821
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 854
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 925
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 992
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1084
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1166
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1218
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1262
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1300
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1342
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1357
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1362
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1367
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1369
    Rows("180:1407").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

The problem is i do this report weekly and the accounts vary with rows due to payments or billing.  So the next time it won't be from row 180 to 1407.

So how do i write a general VBA to select all active cells that the filter sorted, minus the headerow, cut, and paste into sheet 2?

I was trying to mess around with something like

```
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    ActiveSheet.Range("A:O").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        "905263043"
    Set rng = rng.Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1)

    rng.Select
    Selection.Cut
```

but that didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Assumes header in column 1.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet 
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change as needed

With ws

    .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="905263043"

    Dim rng as Range
    Set rng = Intersect(.UsedRange,.UsedRange.Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    rng.Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
    rng.EntireRow.Delete

    .UsedRange.AutoFilter

End With
```

Comment: Yeah, i should have prefaced that.  When it selects the account numbers are interspersed so in between rows 181 to 1084 there will be other account numbers hidden from the filter, so, non-contiguous like the other guys said.

Comment: I tried it and its highlighting the word "Worksheet" in Set ws = Worksheet("Sheet1") with a compile error: sub or function not defined

Comment: Nevermind, i just needed to add an s to worksheet, thanks!

Comment: glad it worked. I added the "s" in my answer, too. Consider marking as answered so others benefit going forward.

Comment: I have another question.  I use this code for more than one account, so for instance, i'll have 905263043, 905706748, 90523402.... and so forth.  But sometimes these accounts fall off the report because they have paid everything so their account balance is 0 and it doesn't show up in the report.  So this macro will still look for say for instance 905706748 which is not there, and since its not there i get an error.  What would be the code i insert so that if it doesn't find that account number to just move on to the next available one?  This is like an "on error" "resume next"?

Comment: @ProximusSeraphimDimitriDavi - That question is whole different issue. To keep SO clean and functioning well, please close out this question (mark as answered) and create a new question and someone can help you there.

Comment: oK STUPID question then, how do i mark this as answered?

Comment: @ProximusSeraphimDimitriDavi - There is a grey check mark just below the up / down voting arrows which are top left corner of answer. Click that check mark :)

Comment: @ProximusSeraphimDimitriDavi - Dumbass? No. Unfamiliar. Yes :) But now you know.